# Get unexpected result from has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, has-one

I have a `Selection` model which has many `Choices` and one `DefaultChoice`.
The relation is structured this way.

Models (I think here there is something wrong)

```
class Selection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :choices, dependent: :delete_all
  has_one  :default_choice, class_name: 'Choice'
end

class Choice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to Selection
end
```

Migration

```
create_table :selections do |t|
  t.references :default_choice, index: true
end
create_table :choices do |t|
  t.belongs_to :selection
end
```

Somehow something is not right:

```
# let's say:
selection = Selection.find(1)
selection.choices << Choice.find(1)
selection.choices << Choice.find(2)
selection.default_choice = Choice.find(2)
selection.save!

# then
selection.default_choice_id = 2
# but
selection.default_choice.id = 1
```

How come?!

`selection.default_choice` generates this query:

```
Choice Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "choices".* FROM "choices" WHERE "choices"."selection_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["selection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: Basically `selection.default_choice` returns always the first choice of `selection.choices`.

Comment: Can you post the SQL query that runs when you do `selection.default_choice`

Comment: I updated the question adding the SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same model `Choice` for both relationships `has_many :choiches` and `has_one :default_choice`. So when you query `has_one :default_choice` result are all from `choices` table and with `has_one` you only get one result which is the first it finds referenced to Selection object.

---

**UPDATE**

To implement default on has_many you can do something like add column on Choice model that will be true if it's default choice. Then has_one relationship would need to have scope to get only choice that is default true like this:

```
has_one :default_choice, -> { where default_choice: true }, class_name: 'Choice'
```

Comment: This is clear to me. But how can I set a specific `default_choice` then?

Comment: That's a whole another question than you've asked. 
You can do something like add column on Choice that will be `true` if it's default choice. Then has_one relationship would need to have scope to get only choice that is default true like this: 

`has_one  :default_choice, -> { where default_choice: true }, class_name: 'Choice'`